# CloudFormation Elastic Beanstalk security groups

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am looking to create two Elastic Beanstalk applications and an RDS database, all within CloudFormation, that are connected as such (with no other connectivity)

1. Public Internet <--> API (public EB application)
2. API (public EB application) <--> Internal EB Application
3. API (public EB application) <--> RDS database

The issue I am currently having is that #2 (API to Internal EB application) connectivity is not working. I also want to ensure that the database (and the internal EB application) are *not publicly accessible,* but I am not sure if that is currently the case.

Here is part of my template (with irrelevant parts, such as parameters and some properties --- it does deploy with everything included), excluded:

```
Resources:
  ###  API ###

  API:
    Type: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Application
    Properties:
      ApplicationName: !Sub "${AWS::StackName}-api"

  APIDeployment:
    Type: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Environment
    Properties:
      ApplicationName: !Ref API
      # Some properties excluded
      OptionSettings:
        - Namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment
          OptionName: ALLOWED_HOSTS
          Value: !Sub ".${AWS::Region}.elasticbeanstalk.com,.${AWS::Region}.elb.amazonaws.com"
        - Namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment
          OptionName: INTERNAL_API_URL
          Value: !Sub "http://${InternalAPIDeployment.EndpointURL}"

        # Database Access
        - Namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment
          OptionName: DATABASE_URL
          Value: !Sub "postgres://${DatabaseUsername}:${DatabasePassword}@${APIDatabase.Endpoint.Address}:${APIDatabase.Endpoint.Port}/${DatabaseName}"
        - Namespace: aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration
          OptionName: SecurityGroups
          Value: !Ref InstanceSecurityGroup

  ### Internal API ###

  InternalAPI:
    Type: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Application
    Properties:
      ApplicationName: !Sub "${AWS::StackName}-quizgen"

  InternalAPIDeployment:
    Type: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Environment
    Properties:
      ApplicationName: !Ref InternalAPI
      # Some properties excluded
      OptionSettings:
        - Namespace: aws:elb:loadbalancer
          OptionName: ManagedSecurityGroup
          Value: !GetAtt InternalAPISecurityGroup.GroupId
        - Namespace: aws:elb:loadbalancer
          OptionName: SecurityGroups
          Value: !GetAtt InternalAPISecurityGroup.GroupId

  ### Database ###

  APIDatabase:
    Type: AWS::RDS::DBInstance
    Properties:
      # Some properties excluded
      VPCSecurityGroups:
        - !GetAtt APIDatabaseSecurityGroup.GroupId
    DeletionPolicy: Snapshot

  ### Security Groups ###

  InstanceSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: RDS allows ingress from EC2 instances in this group.
      SecurityGroupIngress: []

  APIDatabaseSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: Allows access to the provisioned database.
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: !Ref DatabasePort
          ToPort: !Ref DatabasePort
          SourceSecurityGroupName: !Ref InstanceSecurityGroup

  InternalAPISecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: Allows access to the Internal API.
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: 80
          ToPort: 80
          SourceSecurityGroupName: !Ref InstanceSecurityGroup
```

Any help on configuring this is greatly appreciated!